# Как сделать, чтобы бот отображал в сети человек или нет. discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Надо чтобы бот писал в информации об участнике сервера, статус его активности (В сети, Неактивен, Не беспокоить, Не в сети), код есть, но везде отображает, что человек не в сети, когда это не так. Что делать?

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx,member:discord.Member = None, guild: discord.Guild = None):`
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Информация о аккаунте", color=ctx.message.author.color)
        embed.add_field(name="Имя:", value=ctx.message.author.display_name,inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=ctx.message.author.id,inline=False)
        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪ Не в сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"
        
        embed.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Аккаунт был создан:", value=ctx.message.author.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Информация о аккаунте", color=member.color)
        embed.add_field(name="Имя:", value=member.display_name,inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=member.id,inline=False)
        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪ Не в сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"
        
        embed.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{member.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Аккаунт был создан:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответил поздно, но вы используете t = ctx.author.status, а надо t = member.status, в добавку убери member = ctx.author, это мешает.
Вот код:

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx,member:discord.Member = None, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    if member == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Информация о аккаунте", color=ctx.message.author.color)
        embed.add_field(name="Имя:", value=ctx.message.author.display_name,inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=ctx.message.author.id,inline=False)
        t = ctx.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = ctx.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪ Не в сети"

        t = ctx.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = ctx.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"
        
        embed.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Аккаунт был создан:", value=ctx.message.author.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Информация о аккаунте", color=member.color)
        embed.add_field(name="Имя:", value=member.display_name,inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=member.id,inline=False)
        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪ Не в сети"

        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"
        
        embed.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{member.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Аккаунт был создан:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```